# IHTMLDocument2->documentElement->outerHTML is too slow recreating HTML from DOM, is there a faster way?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

I've got an IE BHO plugin that sends out via a COM call the HTML of a page that was loaded in the window.

```
// Note all error handling removed for readability :)
STDMETHODIMP CPlugin::get_HTML(long lMaxSize, BSTR *pbstrHTML)
{
    CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
    MSHTML::IHTMLDocument2Ptr pDocument2 = NULL;
    MSHTML::IHTMLDocument3Ptr pDocument3 = NULL;
    hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_Document(&pDispatch);
    hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument3, (void**)&pDocument3);
    MSHTML::IHTMLElementPtr pRoot = pDocument3->documentElement;
    wstring strHTML = pRoot->outerHTML;
    CComBSTR bstrHTML = strOutput.c_str();
    bstrHTML.CopyTo(pbstrHTML);
}
```

However when it encounters a very large page (e.g. "http://sitemap.zillow.com/uncompressed/ForSale_Hood_MedPri_1.xml"), it takes 3 minutes to create the HTML from the DOM.

Is there a way to access the raw HTML/XML?

When you do a 'view page source' in IE, it pops up almost immediately, so internally IE must be using some API that can do what I want.

Thanks,
Shane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in old versions of MSHTML, outerHTML had a O(n^2) performance. However, in newer versions (IE8) this problem is gone. If you have a choice, use IE8 or later.

Otherwise, using IPersistStream::Save is an option. But CreateStreamOnHGlobal won't help you since its implementation is also O(n^2). You'll have to use a custom IStream for that.

Included is an IStream implementation which was made for this purpose and supports quick writes:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <vector>

// an implementation of a write-only IStream.
// needed because the CreateStreamOnHGlobal implementation doesn't handle
// resizes well (N writes seem to take O(N^2) time)
class MyStream :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<MyStream>,
    public IStreamImpl 
{
public: 

    std::vector<char> buf;

BEGIN_COM_MAP(MyStream)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IStream)
END_COM_MAP()

    STDMETHOD(Write) (const void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbWritten);
};
/*

Usage:

    CComPtr<IStream> stream;
    hr = MyStream::CreateInstance(&stream);
    // streamObj will be valid as long as IStream smart pointer lives
    MyStream *streamObj = (MyStream*)stream.p;
 */


STDMETHODIMP MyStream::Write(const void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbWritten) 
{
    buf.insert(buf.end(), (char*)pv, (char*)pv+cb);
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amnon, I'll try it out and then update this question with results.

Comment: Regarding the question below: the IPersistStream probably saves the source in its original encoding. So it can be single byte, two bytes or a variable number of bytes per character (utf-8) depending on the document's encoding.

Comment: Ah, yes. Getting the Charset from the IHTMLDocument2 pointer, I see that 'unicode' generally denotes UTF16, so I hope IE sticks to this, and I hope making the assumption that everything else is UTF8 compatible is not wrong and break stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can QI for IPersistStream and save to a memory stream created by CreateStreamOnHGlobal
Note the document must finished downloading (ready state needs to be complete).

Comment: Ah, thank you for the pointer Sheng Jiang, I'll update this question when I have some working code.

Comment: I tried:
 CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
 MSHTML::IHTMLDocumentPtr pDocument = NULL;
 hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_Document(&pDispatch);
 hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument, (void**)&pDocument);
 IPersistStreamInitPtr persistStream = pDocument;
 IStreamPtr stream = NULL;
 hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &stream);
 hr = persistStream->Save(stream, FALSE);

But that took the same 3 minutes to execute the 'Save'.  So I'm guessing that this mechanism also interacts with the DOM, because doing a 'view page source' in IE still pops up the window almost immediately.

Comment: Strange. The returning data is the original data. See if you can dig the file out of IE's cache http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172607.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amnon, the following code is mostly working for me.

```
// an implementation of a write-only IStream.
// needed because the CreateStreamOnHGlobal implementation doesn't handle
// resizes well (N writes seem to take O(N^2) time)
class MyStream :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<MyStream>,
    public IStream
{
public: 

    std::vector<char> buf;

BEGIN_COM_MAP(MyStream)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IStream)
END_COM_MAP()

    STDMETHOD(Write) (const void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbWritten);

    // Implement IStream abstract functions
    STDMETHOD(Read) (void *pv, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbRead) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(Seek) (LARGE_INTEGER dlibMove,DWORD dwOrigin,ULARGE_INTEGER *plibNewPosition) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(SetSize) (ULARGE_INTEGER libNewSize) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(CopyTo) (IStream *pstm,ULARGE_INTEGER cb,ULARGE_INTEGER *pcbRead,ULARGE_INTEGER *pcbWritten) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(Commit) (DWORD grfCommitFlags) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(Revert) () { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(LockRegion) (ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset,ULARGE_INTEGER cb,DWORD dwLockType) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(UnlockRegion) (ULARGE_INTEGER libOffset,ULARGE_INTEGER cb,DWORD dwLockType) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(Stat) (__RPC__out STATSTG *pstatstg,DWORD grfStatFlag) { return S_OK; };
    STDMETHOD(Clone) (__RPC__deref_out_opt IStream **ppstm) { return S_OK; };
};

STDMETHODIMP MyStream::Write(const void * pv, ULONG cb, ULONG *pcbWritten) 
{
    buf.insert(buf.end(), (char*)pv, (char*)pv+cb);
    return S_OK;
}

// Retrieves the HTML of the current page
STDMETHODIMP CPlugin::get_HTML(long lMaxSize, BSTR *pbstrHTML)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    try
    {
        CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
        MSHTML::IHTMLDocumentPtr pDocument = NULL;

        CComPtr<IStream> mystream;
        hr = MyStream::CreateInstance(&mystream);
        // streamObj will be valid as long as IStream smart pointer lives
        MyStream *streamObj = (MyStream*)mystream.p;

        hr = m_spWebBrowser->get_Document(&pDispatch);

        hr = pDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument, (void**)&pDocument);
        IPersistStreamInitPtr persistStream = pDocument;

        hr = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &stream);
        hr = persistStream->Save(mystream, FALSE);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        TRACE_FN("Got exception somewhere");
    }
    return hr;
}
```

Now the only problem left is how to figure why some it returns me single-byte chars most times, and double-byte chars at other times. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.